# PiOS lite bullseye on my pi 4 keeps saying “Firmware rejected country setting”

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspbian-lite, raspberry-pi-os-buster, firmware

Whenever I run piOS bullseye on my pi4, it keeps saying “firmware rejected country setting” in `sudo dmesg`:[image]

I tried using a completely fresh installation of piOS bullseye without any pre configuration in imager aswell, but same error

I also tried using piOS legacy (buster), I didn’t get the same error there:

````
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Feb 21 08:19:09 2023 from 192.168.43.65
pi4@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.103-v7l+ (dom@buildbot) (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd083] revision 3 (ARMv7), cr=30c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, PIPT instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000001ac00000, size 320 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000002fffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000]   HighMem  [mem 0x0000000030000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003b3fffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 1012736
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 1728 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 196608 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000]   HighMem zone: 816128 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 20 pages/cpu s50828 r8192 d22900 u81920
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s50828 r8192 d22900 u81920 alloc=20*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1011008
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1  smsc95xx.macaddr=E4:5F:01:8E:86:A4 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7a10e5cc-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000014890000-0x0000000018890000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 3601140K/4050944K available (10240K kernel code, 1366K rwdata, 3196K rodata, 2048K init, 882K bss, 122124K reserved, 327680K cma-reserved, 3264512K highmem)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 34355 entries in 101 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 101 pages with 4 groups
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x3c8/0x59c with crng_init=1
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
[    0.000035] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
[    0.000098] bcm2835: system timer (irq = 25)
[    0.000749] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000771] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
[    0.000792] sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
[    0.000810] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 18ns
[    0.001070] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001800] printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001865] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=540000)
[    0.001920] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.002099] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.002298] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.002344] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.003827] cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.004078] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.004554] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.005783] Setting up static identity map for 0x200000 - 0x20003c
[    0.005999] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.006938] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.008165] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.009523] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.010834] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.010991] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.011038] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (432.00 BogoMIPS).
[    0.011068] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.011095] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.011965] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.025901] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 8 rev 0
[    0.026162] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.026215] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.034416] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.035530] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.039575] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.040357] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.040635] audit: type=2000 audit(0.030:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.041278] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.041964] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.042019] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.042434] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.074583] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.090895] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2021-12-01T15:01:54, variant start
[    0.100909] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 71bd3109023a0c8575585ba87cbb374d2eeb038f
[    0.141833] Kprobes globally optimized
[    0.147334] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.151794] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.152265] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.152512] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.152589] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.152679] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.153030] usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.154984] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    1.100079] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    1.100198] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.100379] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    1.100619] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    1.111178] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.111448] IP idents hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    1.112991] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    1.113057] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    1.113142] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    1.113228] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    1.113410] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.113465] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.113736] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.114480] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.114514] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.114543] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.114571] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.114610] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    1.118134] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.118396] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=20 bucket_order=6
[    1.126748] zbud: loaded
[    1.128495] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.129304] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.129381] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.129410] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.129566] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.129599] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.130670] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.130703] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.130909] bounce: pool size: 64 pages
[    1.130966] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    1.131201] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.131233] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.135851] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    1.135904] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
[    1.136007] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x063fffffff -> 0x00c0000000
[    1.136116] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00ffffffff -> 0x0400000000
[    1.197091] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
[    1.197500] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    1.197538] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.197574] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x63fffffff] (bus address [0xc0000000-0xffffffff])
[    1.197687] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    1.197948] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.201425] PCI: bus0: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    1.201466] pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
[    1.201922] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    1.202066] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    1.202518] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.205992] PCI: bus1: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    1.206030] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01-ff] end is updated to 01
[    1.206124] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.206166] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    1.206270] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    1.206310] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.206747] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[    1.206983] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 63
[    1.215700] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.216028] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.216914] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    1.229341] brd: module loaded
[    1.241793] loop: module loaded
[    1.243574] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.248540] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    1.345145] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    1.346352] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    1.346451] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.346535] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.394352] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.394406] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.397782] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000060000000890
[    1.399139] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.10
[    1.399181] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.399218] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.399248] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.10.103-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    1.399279] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.400042] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.400158] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.400844] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.400888] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.400934] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.401449] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.10
[    1.401489] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.401525] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.401556] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.10.103-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    1.401586] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.402302] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.402390] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.404072] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.404394] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.404408] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.404423] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.404442] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.404902] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.405059] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.405287] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.406958] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    1.410310] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.410344] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.411053] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    1.411646] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.415786] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.416140] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.416359] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.416389] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.422220] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.422282] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.422415] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.422776] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.422957] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.422999] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.423878] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    1.423910] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    1.423938] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    1.435762] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.436096] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.436185] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 36, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.442875] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    1.443982] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    1.444017] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    1.472446] of_cfs_init
[    1.472730] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.494035] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    1.495746] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.497451] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.500488] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    1.502188] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.510268] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.mmc [fe340000.mmc] using ADMA
[    1.510954] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=7a10e5cc-02...
[    1.545937] mmc0: Problem switching card into high-speed mode!
[    1.546164] mmc0: new SDHC card at address 0001
[    1.547156] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 ASTC 14.6 GiB
[    1.550500]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.572340] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.584679] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.584773] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    1.599452] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.609733] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2048K
[    1.615310] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    1.615340]   with arguments:
[    1.615354]     /sbin/init
[    1.615369]   with environment:
[    1.615383]     HOME=/
[    1.615397]     TERM=linux
[    1.695038] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.877654] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    1.877701] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.877735] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    1.879729] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.880016] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.205029] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.346586] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    2.346636] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.346672] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[    2.346702] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[    2.346731] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
[    2.743241] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    2.983804] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.985293] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    3.110911] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    3.111910] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    3.177602] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    4.313671] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.325630] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.326359] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    4.327128] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.330337] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    4.331137] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    4.331855] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.332353] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    4.333619] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    4.335032] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    5.342024] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    5.441799] systemd-journald[115]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    6.217732] rpivid-mem feb00000.hevc-decoder: rpivid-hevcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb00000 length 0x00010000
[    6.218436] rpivid-mem feb10000.rpivid-local-intc: rpivid-intcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb10000 length 0x00001000
[    6.219047] rpivid-mem feb20000.h264-decoder: rpivid-h264mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb20000 length 0x00010000
[    6.219661] rpivid-mem feb30000.vp9-decoder: rpivid-vp9mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb30000 length 0x00010000
[    6.542461] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.544609] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    6.544634] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    6.552298] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[    6.590424] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.636986] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 8 channels
[    6.717423] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    6.863982] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0
[    6.868259] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    7.028929] [drm] No displays found. Consider forcing hotplug if HDMI is attached
[    7.029457] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe600000.firmwarekms (ops vc4_fkms_ops [vc4])
[    7.030520] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for gpu on minor 1
[    7.094899] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.094906] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.224897] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.256811] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.257272] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    7.267894] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    7.267947] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    7.272034] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.276491] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[    7.277032] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[    7.277529] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[    7.278167] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[    7.278199] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[    7.278224] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[    7.278258] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[    7.278280] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[    7.278488] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[    7.283925] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    7.283991] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    7.301283] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    7.309563] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    7.309635] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[    7.322085] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video18
[    7.322133] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 image_fx
[    7.455420] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[    7.466120] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    7.467714] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    7.746222] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    7.867098] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    7.867225] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    7.879425] mt7601u 1-1.3:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[    7.890717] mt7601u 1-1.3:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[    7.895260] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Jan  4 2021 19:56:29 version 7.45.229 (617f1f5 CY) FWID 01-2dbd9d2e
[    8.322362] mt7601u 1-1.3:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[    8.568253] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[    8.570560] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
[    9.740614] random: crng init done
[    9.740636] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   10.032549] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[   10.715543] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   11.045128] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   11.393436] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): resizing filesystem from 397312 to 3760128 blocks
[   11.437950] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[   13.124525] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII (RX delay)
[   13.126402] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[   14.613556] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   14.655895] wlan1: authenticate with d6:62:ea:42:fd:cc
[   14.718693] wlan1: send auth to d6:62:ea:42:fd:cc (try 1/3)
[   14.726503] wlan1: authenticated
[   14.735036] wlan1: associate with d6:62:ea:42:fd:cc (try 1/3)
[   14.751169] wlan1: RX AssocResp from d6:62:ea:42:fd:cc (capab=0x1631 status=0 aid=3)
[   14.786583] wlan1: associated
[   15.678924] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[   16.647476] wlan1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by d6:62:ea:42:fd:cc
[   16.650275] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan1: link becomes ready
[   18.792935] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.793061] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   18.793078] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.793943] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.793968] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.794006] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.287427] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   19.287443] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   19.287506] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   19.287661] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   22.310774] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): resized to 2097152 blocks
[   27.397740] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   27.397761] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   27.397790] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.436409] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): resized to 3670016 blocks
[   33.116325] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): resized filesystem to 3760128
pi4@raspberrypi:~ $```
````

Comment: What country did you set?

Comment: @JaromandaX i am currently in Pakistan, so i set it as "PK", in a discord pi server, someone suggested i should try switching it to US, i tried that aswell but i get the same error

Comment: how are you changing the country?

Comment: I just checked, and PK definitely is rejected, but US isn't, so that should work

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried both ways, through raspi-config, as well as manually changing the country in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, an update: i did a fresh install of bullseye directly from the imager again, this time i did a network install instead of pre-downloading the image and then installing it using imager, set the country to US in imager, booted it up and got the same error "firmware rejected country setting", **BUT**, i tried `sudo apt update`, received a 37kb update, after i updated and rebooted, the error went away!, lol that was weird, then i switched it back to PK and got the error again, then back to US and the error went away, it didn't worked before but now did

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry for wasting your time, i just tried it yesterday and it wasn't working, but it's working now suprisingly, maybe that 37 kb of update did something? well anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @JaromandaX another update, when i connect my pi4 to my phone's wifi hotspot, i get the error again, but it goes away when i connect it to my laptop's hotspot (my phone only supports 2.4Ghz band, whereas my laptop can do both 2.4 and 5 Ghz, but i forced my laptop to only use 2.4Ghz and make sure that pi connects to that to narrow down variables to track the problem)

Comment: you haven't wasted my time